# Difference between ACI Code and Eurocode in Stiffness modifiers?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, building-design, eurocodes

According to the ACI Code stiffness modifiers (modifiers used to reduce the moment of inertia) are used for each structural elements for example 0.7 for columns and 0.35 for beams...

For those who do seismic and/or wind design according to Eurocode where are these modifiers used and if they are not clearly available like in the ACI Code how does the code apply these modifiers ? does eurocode use a coefficient to reduce the compressive strength of the concrete instead of using these coefficient?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike thank you for your reply, I am sorry if the topic is not clear but I am a frequent ACI user but i do not have a clear idea in the eurocode for seismic design for building. What i do understand is that the eurocode uses a coefficient to reduce the strength of the concrete as a material but i just need to know if that coefficient is the equivalent of stiffness modifiers in the ACI Code.

Answer (score -1):

euro code also use the same approach but the values are different euro code allows to use a value of 0.5 for beams columns and slabs.